# Detecting bitly link redirection

Tags: django, python-2.7

I've been using the bitly api in a django view to shorten links to link towards a specific page.
However, the content of this page needs to be different for people who use the bitly link as this link is being shared with people.

Is there a way to find out if the page was redirected from a bitly link? Or just redirected in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reliable way to detect this is to shorten the URL with a special parameter that you can later detect on your view.

So, for instance, instead of shorting the URL http://example.com/article/1/ you should short http://example.com/article/1/?bitly=1.

Then on your view you can detect the "bitly" request parameter using:

```
from_bitly = bool(request.GET.get('bitly', False))
```